# How to comfortably work with paths that are relative to the working directory in Deno?

Tags: deno

My original motivation was to run a Deno script from Crontab on Ubuntu.

First I did not know that paths are relative to the working directory, not the executing module.

My script was reading and writing files to a disk, so I got errors like

```
error: Uncaught NotFound: No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

I was pointed out that this problem can be solved with `import.meta.url`.

I modified the path to resolve it from `import.meta.url` and this solution worked fine with read/write operations.

But I encountered another problem with `.env` file.
It was a surprise to me that even the dotenv module uses paths relative to the working directory.

The dotenv module has the option to specify the path with `config({path:___})`, but I think it is too much to overwrite the default location.

Eventually, changing the working directory to the script's root directory before running the script in crontab was a simpler solution.

```
* * * * * cd ____; deno run ___
```

But I still have doubts if this is the most efficient way.

Is there something better to changing a directory in such cases?

It would be nice to have a mode when running deno, which would make paths relative to the executing module excluding modules which are imported with URLs.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [`Deno.mainModule`](https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#Deno.mainModule), which is a reference to the file URL of the entrypoint module you passed to `deno`. You can use it with the [`deno.land/std/path`](https://deno.land/std@0.102.0/path) module to get the directory of the entrypoint for your program, and then use [`Deno.chdir()`](https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#Deno.chdir) to change your current working directory so that all relative paths (which are implicitly relative to [`Deno.cwd()`](https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#Deno.cwd)) are then relative to that directory.

`/repo/relative-path.ts`:

```js
import * as path from 'https://deno.land/std@0.102.0/path/mod.ts';
export {path};

export const mainModuleDir = path.dirname(path.fromFileUrl(Deno.mainModule));
```

`/repo/main.ts`:

```js
import {mainModuleDir, path} from './relative-path.ts';

Deno.chdir(mainModuleDir);

const entrypointRelativePath = path.resolve('hello', 'world.json');
console.log(entrypointRelativePath);
```

Then, run your script:

```
$ cd /different/unrelated/path
$ deno run --allow-read /repo/main.ts
/repo/hello/world.json
```

You can use `mainModuleDir` as a base for any entrypoint-relative paths you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have checked your solution, but it does not fit my problem. As you suggest we can find the correct path from `Deno.mainModule`. But to make it work we would need to modify each path related reference. For example, if I need to load `.env`, I would write `import { config } from "https://deno.land/x/dotenv/mod.ts";
console.log(config({ path:path.join(mainModuleDir,".env") }))`
But I am looking for a solution, when you don't need to modify every path related reference.

Comment: @Olek I have updated my answer. Does it now answer your question?

Comment: Deno.chdir() works perfectly for one file. Maybe I am asking too much. But is there a way to implement the solution you suggest in every .ts file automatically? I guess editing the Deno source code would do the thing, but I don't know Rust and the changes should be reimplemented after each update.

Comment:  "automatic" behavior is generally an anti-pattern in Deno (so that code is easier to reason about). The only ways I think that what you want would be possible are (1) editing the Deno source and recompiling or (2) creating a script execution framework using [`Deno.run`](https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#Deno.run), passing the entrypoint and your desired CWD in the [`RunOptions`](https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#Deno.RunOptions), so that the subprocess actually runs your script.

Comment: I agree with you. For me editing the Deno source code is not an option. Writing a wrapper function to run Deno scripts is more realistic. But I don't understand why the Deno development team does not implement such a feature. It would not hurt the Deno principles. Adding a flag, for example '-- relative' to mark that you want to run the script from any path, would be a great benefit.

Comment: @Olek, the Deno team probably doesn't consider that because there is no end to the options that they would have to invent through that reasoning (surely resolving relative paths is not the only thing where someone on the internet could think of a nifty magic shortcut) and it makes the Deno code diverge from web standards more.